# Stained Glass Cheat to Transform into Clear Glass

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a Minecraft command that transforms all Stained Glass in the world into normal Clear Glass? I built a structure with Stained Glass but I don't like the colours. Does anyone know how to change this?

Comment: You definitely can’t do it for the whole world. You’d have to select the specific area that contains your structure. Unfortunately I don’t know the specific command, but “fill” with “replace” is where I’d start. The issue is that color is a NBT tag, I think.

Comment: No, it's not. It was a block state before, now it's just a regular block ID.

Answer (score 2):

There is no command to change all stained glass in the entire world, but you can use `/fill` with `replace` to replace blocks of a certain type in an area with a different blocks.

This command would replace all white stained glass in the selected area with regular glass:

```
/fill <coordinates for 2 opposite corners of the area> minecraft:glass replace minecraft:white_stained_glass
```

Your situation is a bit more difficult, because you want to change more than one type of blocks at once. You could repeat the command from above for all types of stained glass, but you would need 16 commands for that.

Minecraft has an `impermeable`-tag that happens to include all solid forms of glass (no glass panes). You can use that instead to change all types of glass at once:

```
/fill <coordinates for 2 opposite corners of the area> minecraft:glass replace #minecraft:impermeable
```